# Jquery Ajax Validation Remote field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to check whether the emailId is already registered or not. Following is my code:-

```
<input type="email" name="user_email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
```

Following is my jquery validation:-

```
$('#signup_form').validate({
    rules: {
        user_email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: "/check_email_exist/",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    email: function() {
                        return $( "#signup_form :input[name='user_email']" ).val();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    },
    messages:{
        email: {
            remote: jQuery.validator.format("{0} is already taken.")
        }
    }
});
```

The problem I'm facing is that it sends a request only once to the server. If I the email, irrespective of the fact that its registered or not, it will send a request to the server for the first time and then if type again another email, it wont send the request to the server.

What am I doing wrong over here??

Also, I get the response from the server as `True/False`. Irrespective of the response I get, my `remote` message is not being displayed. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the mistake. I was sending the response as `True/False`, whereas it should be `true/false` (Mind the case).